# If one were to have boots made of Vibranium, could one fall from any height?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe

Vibranium is a fictional metal from the Marvel universe, with interesting properties, it "possesses the ability to absorb all vibrations in the vicinity as well as kinetic energy directed at it."

It became the subject of an argument between myself and some friends earlier today, that if one were to have boots made of such a metal, could one fall from any height without injury?

Comment: This comes kinda close to a science question so I'm hesitant to answer, but: vibranium boots would not protect your legs bones from the force of the rest of your body slamming *down from above*.

Comment: [Originally posted on Physics](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/178179) but closed because it's a "what if" about fictional equipment.

Comment: I seem to remember both Black Panther and Noh-Var(Marvel Boy) having vibranium soled boots that somehow let them run up walls. I think T'Challa used them more for their sound deadening stealth aspect.

Comment: Also in Winter Soldier Cap jumps what looks like about ten stories and lands on his vibranium shield with only mild discomfort. Of course that could be chalked up to his super soldier serum enhanced healing and constitution and a normal person would be more seriously injured.

Comment: To extend on what @MichaelEdenfield said, I imagine that your legs wouldn't break... But you wouldn't have much fun cleaning up all your former innards that are currently out-ars.

Comment: @Monty129 IIRC, he also jumps down onto one of the helicarriers and lands in a kneeling position, without using his shield to cushion it. The jump is from a ridiculous height.

Comment: @phantom42 I remember that now. There are some inconsistencies in his abilities in the MCU.

Comment: Should this be retitled to clarify that it is about surviving a _fall_ from any height?

Comment: @Rhettorical I think it should. So I have. Thanks.

Comment: @SomeGuy I'll admit I was a little confused, trying to imagine using vibranium boots to jump really high, then I read Clyde's answer and it made sense.

Comment: Wrong continuity.  You want a pair of boots that can do that, talk to the folks at Aperture Science.

Comment: This question reminds me of the following..."business opportunity": https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wX9Sc88qreg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot jump from **any** height. The vibranium would have to nullify all kinetic energy.

---

You could however jump from a **greater** height. From the wiki, if the source is correct, it only reduces it the amount of kinetic energy by absorbing it. The amount higher depending on how much is absorbed.

**Quote from the Wiki** -

> "A different variety of Vibranium found in Wakanda absorbs soundwaves and other vibrations, **including kinetic energy.**"

**Second quote from the Wiki** -

> "The Wakandan isotope possesses the ability to absorb all vibrations in the vicinity as well as **kinetic energy directed at it**. The energy absorbed is stored within the bonds between the molecules that make up the substance. As a result, the more energy vibranium absorbs the tougher it becomes. **There are limits** to the capacity of the energy that can be stored, although the exact limitations are not yet known."

- From above - **"kinetic energy directed at it"** - Make sure you land on them feet.

[Wiki Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vibranium)

Comment: @Draft Changed the answer to make more sense, thanks for the input.

Comment: the problem is that even landing on your feet, the kinetic energy of your torso would be distributed into your femur and shatter it long before it reached your boots

Comment: @Miachael Edenfield - The kinect energy would originate from the ground pushing back up against your body when you touch the ground. IE from your feet. That's why I stated at the end, make sure you land on your feet.

Comment: But you're the one that's moving, not the ground ;)

Comment: From a real physics point of view, the whole idea of absorbing kinetic energy is unclear since KE depends on your reference frame, and it can't just be resistant to *changes* in KE  energy or Captain America wouldn't be able to accelerate and decelerate his shield to carry it with him...maybe the idea is just that it distributes kinetic energy evenly across the entire surface? And/or that every collision between it and another object is perfectly [elastic](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/elacol.html) sort of like an even better [Super Ball](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Ball)?

Comment: ...alternately I suppose we could imagine collisions with the shield are totally *inelastic*, so that linear kinetic energy is transformed into some other form (like heat, or potential energy in bonds of molecules in the shield), reducing it as much as possible in the shield's initial rest frame, though it can't be to zero since momentum still has to be conserved, and any change in the shield's momentum means a change in its linear velocity v which means a change in its linear kinetic energy (since kinetic energy is (1/2)*m*v^2 )

Comment: Is this a Wakandan variety? It seemed like Shuri made that suit which absorbs kinetic energy.

Answer (score 1):

One could not fall from an indefinite height because the acceleration of the body would have nothing to do with the strength or absorption capabilities of the boots.

If I were falling at a 60 m/s, weighed 80 kg, and stopped in 1/4 of a second, applying newton's second law of motion gives us a force of a bit over a ton and a half. Your bones would probably snap, and there would be nothing the vibranium could do.

Comment: If you're in a suit completly made out of vibrantium, and since that matter absorbs any type of vibrations you wouldn't feel a thing

Comment: Compression of your flesh inside the suit would be a problem.

Comment: but you'd have to consider that the cause of the deceleration is the kinetic movement of the ground towards you, movement that is magically absorbed by the vibranium and not transferred to you. It acts as a buffer. (No one said it was real physics)