# Can a cage made out of Vibranium contain The Hulk?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-incredible-hulk

Vibranium absorbs Kinetic Energy and becomes stronger. On the other hand, The Hulk's rage makes him stronger.

Which one will win? **Can a cage made out of Vibranium contain The Hulk?** Has this thing been happened in the comics?

Comment: In [Ultimate Avengers II](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_Animated_Features#Ultimate_Avengers_2:_Rise_of_the_Panther) Vibranium was shown to be largely useless against the Hulk because it becomes brittle when exposed to the Gamma radiation emitted by him when he becomes especially angry.

Comment: Most likely not. However, in the MCU at least, there simply isn't enough Vibranium in the world to make a Hulk-sized cage.

Comment: Vibranium and adamantium for that matter are physical materials and therefore have limits. But the Hulk is fuelled by anger which has no limits. So I'm going to say no.

Comment: @Omegacron Tony has already synthesized Vibranium with his table-top particle accelerator. It's just a matter of time before he would build a Hulk Cage after his Project Veronica cage failed.

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433 that wasn't Vibranium, it was a completely new element. It WAS referred to as vibranium in the IM2 novelization, but that was overridden by the dialogue in "CA: First Avenger". Tony tried to patent it as "badassium" but wasn't able to.

Comment: @Richard : I thought in the animated films, it was only the processed version of the element used by the Chitauri that got brittle. Pure vibranium (like from the Wakanda meteor) didn't seem to have that problem did it?

Comment: @Omegacron - Again, wiki-sourced answer. That said, although I've not seen the film for quite some time it definitely chimes with my recollection.

Comment: @Richard I have both movies - maybe I'll watch again and see. I know they found that the ship hulls were brittle where the Hulk had punched them, but I thought they determined that the weakness was introduced when the Chitauri processed the vibranium. It's a nitpicky difference, I know.

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433 I don't think the Veronica cage was designed to contain the Hulk forever, just long enough for Iron Man to get his Hulkbuster armor on.

Comment: @Omegacron **Age of Ultron SPOILERS** in this comment: In the latest Avengers movie, the story shows pirates mining Vibranium in large quantities from Wakanda (well, "Africa", but they even mention "Wakandan" dialect), so it's not unlikely that we'll see lots of Vibranium in future movies. Certainly in the Infinity Wars movies (Avengers 3 and 4) where Black Panther will be appearing.

Comment: @TylerH I know. I wrote that for fun.

Comment: Guys, please. Veronica is the name of the Hulkbuster armor, not the name of the cage. Or am I wrong on this one?

Comment: @TylerH Didn't they say that was the last of it?

Comment: @Kalissar Veronica launched from a satellite which included a cage for Hulk, too.

Comment: @Kalissar Not sure, but it's unclear from the movie. From their discussion Veronica was designed as a "last resort" either by Banner or with heavy input from Banner. I tend to think Stark doesn't take much input from others when it comes to his suit, but FWIW the cage did not look like the typical Stark gadget (it wasn't bright red and gold, for one...), so I lean more toward Veronica being the cage, or *both* the cage and the armor.

Comment: @Rawling I don't recall that line, I'll have to wait until I see it again to tell.

Comment: @Omegacron Cap's shield isn't all vibranium in existence.  SHIELD has used vibranium on the Bus and the cabin in *Agents of SHIELD*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could the Hulk become powerful enough to break adamantium?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/17597/could-the-hulk-become-powerful-enough-to-break-adamantium)

Comment: @cde I initially thought that as well, but after reading the linked Q, there is no mention of Vibranium specifically. Although, some may argue that Vibranium is a form of Adamantium.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In my answer to another question about vibranium [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/87120/if-one-were-to-have-boots-made-of-vibranium-could-one-fall-from-any-height/87122#87122) (about vibranium boots allowing you to jump from greater heights) there is a quote about how vibranium can absorb kinetic energy. So in that sense it would be a better cage. But the one flaw is that it can only absorb a *finite* amount. With many of us knowing that the Hulk's strength is incredible (and seemingly unending), given enough time and anger he would eventually be able to force his way through.

Quote from [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vibranium) -

> "Vibranium found in Wakanda absorbs soundwaves and other vibrations,
>   including **kinetic energy**."

Second quote from the [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vibranium) -

> "The Wakandan isotope possesses the ability to absorb all vibrations
>   in the vicinity as well as kinetic energy directed at it. The energy
>   absorbed is stored within the bonds between the molecules that make up
>   the substance. As a result, the more energy vibranium absorbs the
>   tougher it becomes. **There are limits to the capacity of the energy
>   that can be stored**, although the exact limitations are not yet
>   known."

I think enough time and rage would allow the Hulk to break through.

Comment: In one of the "Infinity Gauntlet" comics, Thanos was able to shatter Captain America's shield with a blow from his fist. I don't know if that was a vibranium shield at the time, but if so, it definitively answers the question.

Answer (score 15):

Short answer, no. On several occasions we've actually seen the Hulk damaging or breaking vibranium artifacts.

- In [Ultimate Avengers II](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_Animated_Features#Ultimate_Avengers_2:_Rise_of_the_Panther) Vibranium was shown to be largely useless against the Hulk because it becomes brittle when exposed to Gamma radiation (which he emits when he becomes *especially* angry).
- In Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D., we see an enormous fist-print in the vibranium-coated walls of [The Retreat](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Retreat), a safe-house used to contain potentially violent 'guests'. It follows that if he can dent it, then he can break out eventually.

[image]

Comment: I don't doubt you Richard, but where do we find out that the honeycomb walls are vibranium?

Comment: The walls of safe house were Vibranium-lined, not made entirely of Vibranium.

Comment: @Omegacron - I got the info from the MCU wiki link. It could easily be wrong (as wikis so often are).

Comment: I think they mentioned something about it in the first Lady Sif episode, when they had Lorelai locked up on the plane.  Can't remember for sure, though, and even if so that doesn't guarantee that this room was built the same way as the similar room on the Bus.

Comment: @Nerrolken, if the Bus had vibranium (and I don't know if it did, it would ***heavily*** imply the safehouse did. I mean, we don't even know for sure why the honeycomb walls were there -- maybe it was decor -- but the obvious implication was that it was "the same" as the room on the Bus.